# React Redux Firebase - onAuthStateChanged delay prevents from using life cycle methods

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I am implementing Firebase authentication in a React Redux application.

**Issue:** 
I am running in to an issue that is preventing me from using React's component lifecycle methods in support of conditional rendering.

In navigating between pages, when each page/component loads, the initial **cUser**(current user) state is null. This is because there is a bit of a delay in waiting for Firebase's 'onAuthStateChanged' method to resolve and **cUser**(current user) state is updated in Redux. The component loads before state has a chance to be updated with the current user. Not surprising as this is an async process.

**Question:**
What is the best way to deal with this?

There are plenty of ways I can work around this, but using component lifecycle methods would be much more efficient.

I've seen related posts from 2016 instructing to check localStorage, but when accessing localStorage, there does not seem to be anything Firebase related. I'm assuming Firebase no longer stores user data in localStorage.

---

Code:

My App component invokes the 'onAuthStateChanged' Firebase method.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { firebase } from '../firebase';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import '../styles/styles.css';
import { LOBBY, HISTORY, TOPS, LANDING, SIGN_UP, SIGN_IN, FORGOT_PASSWORD, ACCOUNT, SIGN_OUT } from '../config/routes';

import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Lobby from './Lobby';
import History from './History';
import Tops from './Tops';

import Landing from './registration/Landing';
import SignIn from './registration/SignIn';
import SignUp from './registration/SignUp';
import SignOut from './registration/SignOut';
import Account from './Account';
import ForgotPassword from './registration/ForgotPassword';


class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(Object.keys(localStorage));
    const { signOutUser, updateUserAuth } = this.props;

    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        updateUserAuth(authUser);
      } else {
        signOutUser();
      }
    });
  }
  checkAuth() {
    if (this.props.cUser) {
      return <Header />;
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('cUser: from APP', this.props.cUser);
    return (
      <div className="lightGray">
        <div className="container ">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              {this.checkAuth()}
              <Route exact path={LOBBY} component={Lobby} />
              <Route exact path={HISTORY} component={History} />
              <Route exact path={TOPS} component={Tops} />

              <Route exact path={LANDING} component={Landing} />
              <Route exact path={SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
              <Route exact path={SIGN_IN} component={SignIn} />
              <Route exact path={SIGN_OUT} component={SignOut} />
              <Route exact path={FORGOT_PASSWORD} component={ForgotPassword} />
              <Route exact path={ACCOUNT} component={Account} />
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps({ cUser }) {
  return { cUser };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Action to update the current user state.

```js
export const updateUserAuth = user => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const payload = {
      displayName: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      refreshToken: user.refreshToken,
      userId: user.uid,
    };
    return dispatch({ type: CURRENT_USER, payload });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

cUser(current user) will always be null on Account page.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../actions';

class Account extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.cUser) {// always null
      this.props.getUserData(this.props.cUser.idToken); 
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <div className="row valign-wrapper section">
          <h1 className=" bigHeader">Account</h1>
          <div className="col s2 right-align" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps({ cUser }) {
  return { cUser };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Account);
```

firebase implementation

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const prodConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxx',
  projectId: 'xxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
};

const devConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxx',
  projectId: 'xxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
};

const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? prodConfig
  : devConfig;

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by storing userId in localStorage.

```js
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        localStorage.setItem('userId', authUser.uid);
        updateUserAuth(authUser);
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('userId');
        signOutUser();
      }
    });
```